# Easier formatting for variable ranges in list comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

If I have a list comprehension that is essentially this:

```
result = [function(i,j,k,l) for i in range(3) for j in range(3)
    for k in range(3) for l in range(3)]
```

It does what I want, but it looks ugly.  I'm fairly new to Python, but it seems that Python  would have some kind of built-in to allow me to sum over all possible combinations of the 4 letters ijkl in a less cumbersome fashion.  Is my intuition correct, or am I stuck staring at that long ugly line?

Comment: Check out the itertools module.

Comment: What you want to loop over is the Cartesian product, and you can use `itertools.product` (e.g. in your case, `result = [function(*args) for args in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=4)]`.  This is a duplicate of lots of questions, but I admit it's sometimes hard to hit on the right phrase to search for.

Comment: @DSM Why not post this as an answer?

Comment: @LevLevitsky: 'cause I was hoping someone would choose a good dup..

Comment: For the record, I personally find your current code very clear and to the point, if ever so slightly verbose.

Comment: @DSM thanks, I did assume this question had already been asked and answered, but I couldn't find the phrase that pulled up the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Because no one came up with a duplicate for this, here's my answer, just for the record (though DSM already gave a good answer in the comments where he also used `itertools.product`, and that's the meat of the solution):

```
result = itertools.starmap(function, itertools.product(range(3), repeat=4))
```

`starmap` returns an iterator (just like Python 3's `map`), so you might want to wrap this expression in in a list, and at that point DSM's answer is probably be even more readable.